# python-dotenv not working in custom package

Tags: python, environment-variables, python-packaging

I have been using python-dotenv successfully in my python app. I am now starting to refactor and creating packages to hold some of my support files. When i move the .env file into the package folder my env variables are not set.

As an example

The following structure works.

```
/
- app.py
- .env
```

```
#app.py
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
print(os.getenv("DB_PASSWORD"))
```

Result: **kdfhsffdfjd**

The following structure does not work

```
/
- database
  - __init__.py
  - connection.py
  - .env
- app.py
```

```
#connection.py
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()
print(os.getenv("DB_PASSWORD"))
```

Result: **None**

```
# app.py
from database import connection
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually call `load_dotenv` function. You can pass the .env file path as an argument or you could try to use `find_dotenv` method:

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

# or
load_dotenv(path_to_dotenv_file)
```

Comment: Apologies, load_dotenv() is already in my code, I had just missed it from my example. I have updated the post. I have also tried find_dotenv() with no success.

Comment: Habe you tried providing .env file path as an argument to `load_dotenv`? This is also what my answer suggests

Comment: That did not work, but I have found the solution. I seem to have to put the .env file in the root of my project, NOT in the package. I have tried to specify the path with load_dotenv("./.env") but it still does not work. To be honest, this probably works OK, because I don't want to include the .env file in my GIT repo anyway. So users of the package should add entries to the .env file in their own project. (If that makes sense)

Comment: I do agree that storing in the project root would be nicer but loading not from root should also work just fine, you should have tried with an absolute file, not relative. If you put your .env file not in the project root it doesn't mean that you need to add it to GIT so I believe that'a a bit unrelated to the .env location.

Comment: I understand about not having to add the .env to GIT, but it makes it more difficult to describe to end users in documentation, where they should create the .env file, although putting an .env.exmaple file makes it's easier.

Answer (score 1):

for future reference, I had the same problem, but none of the above helped -
I was using pipenv, and it turns out I that when I was running the pipenv shell from another location, which isn't the project root folder, it wouldn't load antything from the .env file.
after deactivating the shell, and running it again from the root folder, it worked fine.

Comment: No, not exactly. the answer you mentioned didn't work for me. 
I wasn't talking about the location of the .env file, but the location from where you load your virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to keep the .env file in the root of my project. This makes sense on a number of levels.

1. It ensures that only one .env file exists.
2. The whole point of the .env file is that I don't want to publish my secrets in the Git repo. If the .env file was located in the package, users would have to edit the package by adding a .env file, potentially in multiple places.

Anyway, in summary, I can still use load_dotenv() in the package, but the .env file had to be in the root of the project. @GProst has suggested that I should be able to access it in the package, but I was not able to get that to work.